# MemoryRouter TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, enzyme

I have a redux container which I want to mount in my test case. It has a component which is using react-router link. Mounting the container was throwing me history not defined error, after reading this https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/testing.md I implemented MemoryRouter, now the history error is gone, but I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined
      at Object.createPath (node_modules/history/PathUtils.js:47:26)
      at Link.render (node_modules/react-router-dom/Link.js:76:44)
```

My test case:

```
it('should load popup component', () => {
    const container = mount(
        <Provider store={ store }>
            <MemoryRouter initialIndex='2' initialEntries={ ['/', 'home'] } >
                <HomeContainer />
            </MemoryRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
    assert.equal(container.find('PopUp').length, 1, 'Popup component is not mounted');
});
```

My Component:

```
class Home extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.init();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        document.title = 'Home';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Popup />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Home;
```

My Container:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    data: state.mainReducer.data
});
const HomeContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, { init })(Home);
export default HomeContainer;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is because your `<Link to="undefined" />`, make sure that the `to` value is valid and not undefined/empty.

Comment: Yeah you are right, my URL was undefined. Thank you :)

Comment: This has saved my day. Thanks.